# CSS Styling: Should I specify the element type?

Tags: css, dom

Which of the following is better code:

```
div#style1{

}
```

or

```
#style1{
}
```

Also, should the element type be specified for classes or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "better".

Because of [the way the style system matches rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS#How_the_Style_System_Matches_Rules), `#style1` is faster than `div#style1` (and the same goes for classes). For this reason, conventional wisdom is that the former, less-qualified selector is better.

However, it may be that `div#style1` is more easily understood by the next person<sup>1</sup> editing the CSS than `#style1` (in the specific case you give, probably not - but, for example, the meaning of a selector like `a.external` is immediately obvious to anyone reading it in a way that a bare `.external` isn't).

In cases like that, you have to decide which is more important: making your CSS as straightforward as possible to maintain, or making it (perhaps only very slightly) faster to render.

---

<sup>1</sup> Maybe you in eighteen months, maybe someone else entirely.

Comment: How much of a difference in speed would it make?

Comment: @cloudcoder2000 that's going to depend on your specific code - if rendering speed is an issue, test it; if not, don't waste time worrying about it.

Comment: The performance penalty for anything other than class or id is almost always greatly exaggerated: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/03/10/performance-impact-of-css-selectors/